# Mapping with termwinkey that accepts a v:count

Tags: terminal-buffer, count

In Vim, typically, prefixing a command repeats the action multiple times.

This is not the case for `gt`, which goes to the next tabpage. Whereas `gt` goes to the next tabpage, `2gt` always goes to the second tabpage, `3gt` to the third, and so on.

The `gt` command has a variant that uses termwinkey `<C-w>gt`, so that it can be invoked from the Vim terminal, with the corresponding counted forms being `<C-w>{count}gt`.

I'd like to create a mapping on `Gt` (and correspondingly, `<C-w>Gt`) that performs the repeated action.

All together, the counted forms would be `{count}Gt` and `<C-w>{count}Gt`, e.g. `5gt` and `<C-w>5gt`.

For normal mode, I've no problem with mapping like so:

```
noremap Gt :<C-u>execute join (repeat (['tabnext'], v:count), ' <Bar> ') <CR>
```

However, I'm struggling to write the mapping that involves termwinkey, as it goes by the form `X{count}Y` rather than the usual `{count}X`, so I'm unable to write a mapping from `X` utilizing `v:count`.

Comment: You could get in the habit of traversing your tabs in reverse order by using `gT`. If nothing else, it accepts counts as counts, not tab numbers.

Comment: I would expect tnoremap or the terminal docs to answer this in some fashion (even if saying that counts are not supported)

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. I allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I don't think any of the offered answers address the question as posed, of adding counts in something that resembles the usual form, but they do offer some food for thought. I need to try to come back with some more creativity and do so.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Given the expertise of some of the contributors (@romainl) I'm afraid the answer is somewhere here :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping to a macro to make an action repeatable. In your case I would

```
:nnoremap <silent> Gt @='gt'<cr>
```

With this mapping the count will be applied to repeat the macro and will not be used for `gt` directly. Alas, this only seems to work in normal mode, but not after coming from terminal mode with `termwinkey`.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose:

```
noremap <C-w>2Gt <cmd>execute join (repeat (['tabnext'], 2), ' <Bar> ')<CR>
noremap <C-w>3Gt <cmd>execute join (repeat (['tabnext'], 3), ' <Bar> ')<CR>
noremap <C-w>4Gt <cmd>execute join (repeat (['tabnext'], 4), ' <Bar> ')<CR>
noremap <C-w>5Gt <cmd>execute join (repeat (['tabnext'], 5), ' <Bar> ')<CR>
```

You could also generate all these mappings in a loop.

The problem I noticed is that otherwise Vim considers `<C-w>2` as a complete keysequence and search based on that input for a mapping if any. This is why I believe we have to instruct Vim to eat the number and the following `Gt` key before doing the mapping.

I also notice that `v:count` is not populated in such case.

Answer (score 0):

I have had [these two mappings](https://gist.github.com/romainl/0f589e07a079ea4b7a77fd66ef16ebee) for several years:

```
nnoremap <expr> gt ":tabnext +" . v:count1 . '<CR>'
nnoremap <expr> gT ":tabnext -" . v:count1 . '<CR>'
```

but, despite them being theoretically more intuitive than the default, I could never get used to them.

As mentioned in another answer, `v:count` and `v:count1` are surprisingly unusable after `:help 'termwinkey'` despite commands such as `<C-w>3k` working perfectly. An easy workaround would be to make explicit terminal-mode mappings:

```
tnoremap <C-w>gt  <C-w>:tabnext +1<CR>
tnoremap <C-w>2gt <C-w>:tabnext +2<CR>
tnoremap <C-w>3gt <C-w>:tabnext +3<CR>
" etc.
```